# How to store all users emails in a text file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I need to get all users emails at my rails app into a single text file, what is the right way to get them? I have about 10'000 user, what's the recommended way?

is `heroku rails console` a good choice?

**EDIT**
I have a model `User` and `email` attribute

How to get the result of `User.all.select (:email)`  in to text file?

Comment: We're missing all kinds of context. What kind of users do you have? Do you mean emails they receive as users of your service specifically? Or are you trying to get their emails from other services? Your question assumes we understand who you are and what you're doing and we have no idea.

Comment: Sorry, here the edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is using the console, just run `heroku run rails c` then map the emails from your user model and save the output to a file, something like this:

```
File.write('emails.csv', User.all.map(&:email).join(", "))
```

This will save a csv file in your disk, open it with MS Excel or any text editor

Comment: Can I use this method when there is thousands of records to get?

Comment: I believe @simo is kindly mentioning that you may run out of memory if there are too many records.